# Binding Radio button to an object in MVC 3 VB.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I went through many sites and suggestions but could n't get the binding concept working. I am facing following issue.

I have following Model class as below:
**Master View Model:**

```
    Public Class MasterVM


    Public Property Language As LanguageVM
    Public Property Question As QuestionVM

    Public menus As List(Of MenuVM)

    Public Property UserControlName As String
    Public Property Model As Object

End Class
```

**Language View Model**

```
 Public Class LanguageVM

#Region "Properties"

        Public Property IsEnglish As Boolean

#End Region


    End Class
```

**My Controller class:**

```
Public Class WizardController
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

        '
        ' GET: /Wizard
        Function Index() As ActionResult
            Dim oWizard As New Wizard
            Dim oMasterWizard As New MasterVM
            Dim IsNewlyIniated As Boolean = False
            If (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session(Constants.WizardObjectCollection) IsNot Nothing) Then
                If (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session(Constants.WizardObjectCollection).ToString <> "") Then
                    oMasterWizard = DirectCast(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session(Constants.WizardObjectCollection), MasterVM)
                Else
                    IsNewlyIniated = True
                End If
            Else
                IsNewlyIniated = True
            End If

            If (IsNewlyIniated) Then
                oMasterWizard = oWizard.GetWizardInfo()
                If (Session("Language").ToString() = "Spanish") Then
                    oMasterWizard.Wizard.Language.IsEnglish = False
                Else
                    oMasterWizard.Wizard.Language.IsEnglish = True
                End If

                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session(Constants.WizardObjectCollection) = oMasterWizard

            End If

            Return View("Wizard", oMasterWizard)

        End Function

 <HttpPost()>
        Function GetLanguageInfo(ByVal oLanguage As LanguageVM) As ActionResult
            Try
                Dim a As Integer
                a = 10
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
            End Try
        End Function

    End Class
```

I want to display two radio button in my view displaying language as English and spanish. By default it should be binded to my language class isenglish and isspanish property.

and when post happens i should get the value if user has changed it in Is selected property. how aould i get it.

My ASCX page code is as follow:

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl(Of SBE.Services.MasterWizard.LanguageVM)" %>
<form method="post" action="/Wizard/GetLanguageInfo">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Wizard Language</legend>
    <p>Please select the language for your Wizard</p>

      <%= Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(model) model.IsEnglish, True)%>English  
<%= Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(model) model.IsEnglish, False)%> Spanish     
<input id="btnNext" type="submit" value="Next">
```

One more objective is that once I have binded i want the updated value selected by user in an object and passed it to post action defined in the controller. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason it's not binding is because you posted the name of the object in the radio button as "Language", but it's defined in LanguageVM as "IsEnglish".

To make things simpler I recommend always using, `Html.RadioButtonFor`, there's much less room for error, when you don't have to hard code in the name of the expected variable. Then it should be something like

```
<%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsEnglish, true)%>English 
<%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsEnglish, false)%> Spanish
```

Comment: I tried the above code and in view source I could see the following code: <input id="IsEnglish" name="IsEnglish" type="radio" value="True" />English <input checked="checked" id="IsEnglish" name="IsEnglish" type="radio" value="False" /> Spanish. But for some reason my post action is not trigerring on next button click so d'nt know whether the value is binded or not. any suggestion –

Comment: Thanks Finkelstein it worked. I have updated the solution above in the post.